# How to handle association list as heterogeneous list?

Tags: dhall

I'm trying to use dhall to type an [openapi specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.1/versions/3.0.1.md).
Following the description of a [Security Requirement Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/3.0.1/versions/3.0.1.md#securityRequirementObject) which the open api object have an array of, I write the following code:

```
let SecurityRequirement =
  {
    mapKey: Text
  , mapValue: List Text
  }
in
let req1 : SecurityRequirement =
  { mapKey = "AuthorizationHeader"
  , mapValue = ([] : List Text)
  }
let req2 : SecurityRequirement =
  { mapKey = "Foo"
  , mapValue = ([] : List Text)
  }
let requirements : List SecurityRequirement =
  [ req1, req2 ]
in requirements
```

With this code, I get 
`{"Foo":[],"AuthorizationHeader":[]}` while I'm trying to have 
`[{"Foo":[]},{"AuthorizationHeader":[]}]`.
How can I achieve my goal ?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the type of `SecurityRequirement` to `List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : List Text }` then it behaves the way that you requested:

```hs
let SecurityRequirement = List { mapKey : Text, mapValue : List Text }

let req1
    : SecurityRequirement
    = [ { mapKey = "AuthorizationHeader", mapValue = [] : List Text } ]

let req2
    : SecurityRequirement
    = [ { mapKey = "Foo", mapValue = [] : List Text } ]

let requirements : List SecurityRequirement = [ req1, req2 ]

in  requirements
```

```
$ dhall-to-json <<< './example.dhall' 
[{"AuthorizationHeader":[]},{"Foo":[]}]
```

Comment: It seems so obvious now. Thank you very much !